# Concat multiple values of a single field in one row in crystal report's detail section

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new at crystal report. I am developing a report where i need the displayed output like below:

### Item Code| Description| Unit | Serial

110007   |ABC         |PCs   |TU123416, TU676218, TU789761

There are multiple serial numbers for each item. I want to concat those serials with comma.

I tried few solutions but each of them shows serial number at group footer section.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your report design ? You might need to lower the font size if it's passing the intended section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I have no access to Crystal right now, so I coundn't test it, sorry):

1. Create a group by item.
2. On group header, put a formula like this:

```
shared stringvar serials;
serials := ""; //reset the variable for each item
```

3. You can suppress the group header if you wish or suppress the formula.
4. On group details, put a formula like this:

```
shared stringvar serials;
serials := serials & ", " & {YourTable.Serial}; //concatenation
```

5. Suppress details section.
6. On group footer, put item code, description, unit, and a formula like this:

```
shared stringvar serials;
serials; //it is justing returning the variable as is now
```